# Magento 1 custom router with parameters

Tags: module, magento-1.9, router

I have created a career module and jobs can access from below url.

**mysite.com/careers**

This page shows list of jobs with each job shows "View More" button.

When I click on the "View More" button then open a new page and must be show that selected job full details. So this single page link like to be:-

**mysite.com/careers/jobdetails/index/view/1**

Here "**1**" means **job ID**.

I'm using magento **1.9 version**.

If anyone can help me to fix this appreciate that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your module is setup, so im not sure what exactly the url will need to be, but you can get the parameters within your controller using the following code

```
$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('view');
```

or this which will return an array of all params - *to check you are passing the parameters correctly*

```
$allParams = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
```